# Menu open and close animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problem, when I'm opening menu I need animation like this:

```
@keyframes opening {
  from {
    clip-path: circle(0% at 5%, 10%)
  }

  to {
    clip-path: circle(100%)
  }
}

@keyframes closing {
  from {
    clip-path: circle(100%)
  }

  to {
    clip-path: circle(0% at 5%, 10%)
  }
}
```

On my menu

```
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  background: #1f1f1f;
  display: none;
}
```

Menu hamburger is button and i use javascript to open and close it while adding .classList.toggle(class - display: block) on my button

but closing animation doesn't work like i want

i also try to use transform CSS and other things and it doesn't gave me safe effect like i saw at keyframe

I tried to do a class in CSS .opening {anination-name:opening, duration and etc.} and after i tried to add it with javascript (toggle, settimeout adn etc.) nothing is working well for menu closing animation

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You got a fiddle for us? Hard to see it this way and the limited code you supply.

Comment: Please consider narrowing down the question in the title e.g. "HTML menu open/close animation" so the users can see the relevance faster. There are many technologies using menus. Tags are fine, keep using them, but they require additional attention or search criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this, a `transition` is more suitable:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', () =>
  document.querySelector('.menu').classList.toggle('open')
)
```

```css
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #1f1f1f;
  clip-path: circle(0% at 5% 10%);
  transition: clip-path 2s;
}

.menu.open{
  clip-path: circle(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" ></div>
Click anywhere to try out effect
```

Comment: thanks a lot, problem also was in display:none in my menu when its closed

Answer (score 0):

```
   Just adding basic demo code for your undestanding. 

.loader {
      width: 56px;
      height: 56px;
      border: 8px solid transparent;
      border-top-color: $warning;
      border-bottom-color: $warning;
      border-radius: 50%;
      animation: loader-rotate 1s linear infinite;
      top: 50%;
      margin: -28px auto 0;
    }
    
    @keyframes loader-rotate {
      0% {
        transform: rotate(0); }
      100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg); }
     }
```